# Image randomiser with weight/luck

Tags: javascript, php

I was wondering if `php` could make an image randomiser with a luck system similar to this JavaScript code:

```
function doSingle() {
  var luck = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
    imagesArray = ["tree.png", "wood.png", "tick.png", "logs.png"];
    //These two arrays are rarities, below array is "ssr", super super rare
  var ssrArray = ["mash.jpg", "apples.png", "joji.png", "rap.png"]; 
  lucknumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * luck.length));

  if (lucknumber < 8) {
    function displayImage() {
      var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * ssrArray.length);
      window.canvas.src = ssrArray[num];
    }

    displayImage();
  } else {
    function displayImage() {
      var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesArray.length);
      window.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];
    };

    displayImage();
  }
}

doSingle();
```

I can live with this, but I'd prefer if it was `php` because in JavaScript, the luck can only go upto the integer 10 whereas `php` is limitless.

Is there a way to convert this into php?

(this is my php code so far - off a website with no luck system);

```
<?php
function getImagesFromDir($path) {
    $images = array();
    if ( $img_dir = @opendir($path) ) {
        while ( false !== ($img_file = readdir($img_dir)) ) {
            // checks for gif, jpg, png
            if ( preg_match("/(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)$/", $img_file) ) {
                $images[] = $img_file;
            }
        }
        closedir($img_dir);
    }
    return $images;
}

function getRandomFromArray($ar) {
    $num = array_rand($ar);
    return $ar[$num];
}
?>
```

The reason I want the luck system is because I want to put weight on it, so you don't get Super rares all the time, but to get rares about 70% of the times you click the button.

Comment: Why can luck only go up to 10 in javascript - the luck can only go up to the integer 10?

Comment: @RamRaider yeah

Comment: ? and to re-iterate ~ `the luck can only go upto the integer 10` - why?

Comment: @RamRaider Oh sorry i read that wrong, I just read that somewhere on stack, and math.random() can only generate a number from 0-1 ( so like 0.7538263384)

Answer (score 0):

The generation of random numbers in javascript between a lower and upper limit can simply be achieved using a function like this:

```
function random( min, max ){
    return Math.round( ( min + ( Math.random() * ( max - min ) ) ) );
}
```

So the remaining code can probably be re-factored in javascript using that function - not tested btw but looks ok.  You can set the lower and upper limits for the "luck" number generated by altering the input variables `a,b`

Hope that gives an idea how you could proceed using javascript if the limitation of `10` was a problem

```
function doSingle(a,b){
    var lucknumber=random(a,b);
    var images=[ 'tree.png', 'wood.png', 'tick.png', 'logs.png' ];
    var ssr=[ 'mash.jpg', 'apples.png', 'joji.png', 'rap.png' ];

    var displayImage=function(arr){
        var i=Math.floor( Math.random() * arr.length );
        window.canvas.src = arr[ i ];
    }
    /* perhaps you need to make more conditions here to deal with a large range of `luck` numbers? */
    var arr = lucknumber < 8 ? ssr : images;

    displayImage.call( this, arr );
}
doSingle(0,10);
```

---

I had a look though the files for which you posted links - it looks like the canvas is referring to a standard HTML canvas element so with that in mind I cobbled together this demo which I hope might be of use. You can ignore the php functions at the top - or you could use them to generate suitable arrays of images as shown in the commented code.

The javascript generates a random number between `a` and `b` - where, in this case `a=0` and `b=50` - if this is below `threshold` then the image will be selected from the `super super rare` array

```
<?php
    function getImages( $dir ){
        return array_values( preg_grep( '@(\.jpg$|\.jpeg$|\.png$|\.gif$)@i', glob( $dir . '/*.*' ) ) );
    }
    function randomImage( $dir ){
        $imgs=getImages( $dir );
        return basename( $imgs[ rand( 0, count( $imgs ) - 1 ) ] );
    }

    /*
        You could use these functions to generate the
        source arrays.

        $dir_std_img='c:/wwwroot/images/std';
        $dir_ssr_img='c:/wwwroot/images/ssr';

        $arr_std=json_encode( randomImage( $dir_std_img ) );
        $arr_ssr=json_encode( randomImage( $dir_ssr_img ) );


    */


?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Javascript: Luck Generator</title>
        <script>
            /*

            The image names used in the arrays are based upon the images
            within my directory as shown below. Some differ in file 
            extension to those in your original code - these are, afterall,
            just testing images for me.


            C:\wwwroot\images\tmp\lucky > dir /B
            ----------------------------------

            apples.jpg
            joji.png
            logs.jpg
            mash.jpg
            rap.png
            tick.jpg
            tree.jpg
            wood.jpg

            */



            function drawimage( dir, src, i ) {
                /*
                    take selected random image and
                    add to the canvas. In addition
                    add the luck number. Can clearly
                    be simplified by removing code that
                    positions image centrally and adds 
                    the text.
                */
                var canvas=document.getElementById('cnvs');
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                var img = new Image();

                img.onload = function() {
                    var px=Math.floor( Math.abs( canvas.width - img.width ) / 2 );
                    var py=Math.floor( Math.abs( canvas.height - img.height ) / 2 );

                    ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
                    ctx.drawImage( img, px, py );

                    ctx.font='18px calibri';
                    var message='Lucky number: '+i;
                    var text=ctx.measureText( message );
                    ctx.fillText( message, ( ( canvas.width - text.width ) / 2 ), canvas.height - 20 );
                };
                img.src = dir + src;
            }


            function random( min, max ){
                return Math.round( ( min + ( Math.random() * ( max - min ) ) ) );
            }


            function getlucky(a,b,threshold){
                var imgpath='/images/tmp/lucky/';
                var luckynumber=random(a,b);

                var images=['tree.jpg', 'wood.jpg', 'tick.jpg', 'logs.jpg'];
                var ssr=['mash.jpg', 'apples.jpg', 'joji.png', 'rap.png'];

                var displayImage=function( arr ){
                    drawimage.call( this, imgpath, arr[ Math.floor( Math.random() * arr.length ) ], luckynumber );
                }
                var arr = luckynumber <= threshold ? ssr : images;

                displayImage.call( this, arr );
            }





            document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded',function(){
                document.getElementById( 'bttn' ).addEventListener( 'click', function(){
                    getlucky( 0, 50, 5 );
                }, false );
            },false );
        </script>
        <style>
            canvas{margin:1rem auto;float:none;display:block;}
            input[type='button']{float:none;margin:1rem auto;width:800px;display:block;padding:1rem;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id='cnvs' width=800 height=600></canvas>
        <input id='bttn' type='button' value='Get Lucky' />
        <output></output>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'd have done this sooner but the Rugby was on so this took a backburner... good luck

Comment: no doesn't work for me unfortunately, i'm a noob and i don't get what to modify and whatnot, but thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: sorry for bothering you, it's not that it doesn't work, it's that I don't know what to change if that makes sense - i replaced my original JS script with yours and ran the page, but when I click the button nothing happens anymore? I think it's just me, but i'll accept your answer

Comment: Thank you so much - I ill accept in the end regardless, but it'll be nice if ti worked though! Thanks for your effort

Comment: what is `window.canvas.src`?

Comment: I'm not sure - but it works.  when i remove it, it doesn't work, weird, right?

Comment: Sure, what do you mean? The html and javascript? (I will simplify it)

Comment: here's the links for the html and javascript;

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/3ur0ejor1p6jq1o/saiyanbarrage.html (MAIN html - this has the button that activates the javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I allow myself to post an answer even after 4 years of inactivity on this post, because I find that the proposed randomness algorithms are good but involve multiple conditions afterwards to control it. And then if someone comes across it and is looking for a solution, it can always be useful, after all why limit yourself to time :). For example, if I want to fill a table with 20% more and the rest less, we can therefore ask for a 20% chance directly in our algorithm. without control by multiple if. It's up to you to adapt it to your needs. For me, I needed more and less.

```
var construct_tab = (pourcent, len, symbol_pourcent, symbol_without) => {
  var d = Math.round(len*(pourcent/100));
  return Array.from(Array(len),(x,i)=>{
    var choix = d == 0?symbol_without:symbol_pourcent;
    d = d != 0?d - 1:d;
    return choix;});
};

console.log(construct_tab(20, 6, '+', '-'));
// output: Array ["+", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"]

console.log(construct_tab(90, 6, '+', '-'));
// output: Array ["+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "-"]
```